# List element needs to be clicked twice when checking if it has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

made a basic list with the option to click the items and then it would show the next ul.

This works, but when there is already a list shown, and you try to click on another heading you need to click that heading twice before it shows the related ul.

An example is this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yu8ac6g7/

By default, the extra lists are hidden. To replicate my issue:

- click on the first item so the next ul is shown
- then click on the second so the first ul is hidden and the second is shown.

Now, if you try to click on the first item nothing happens. You have to click the item again before the jQuery action happens. This will be the same until you reload the page.

Any help / a better way of doing what I am trying?

Backup code:

```
$(".expanding_mobile_tab").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('mobile_tab_closed')) {
        $(this).removeClass('mobile_tab_closed').addClass('mobile_tab_open');
        $(".features_mobile_details_tab").hide();
        $(this).next('ul').fadeToggle();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".mobile_detail_tabs").offset().top
        }, 800);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('mobile_tab_open').addClass('mobile_tab_closed');
        $(this).next('ul').fadeOut();
        console.log('close');
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="mobile_detail_tabs count_detail_tabs_1 only_mobile">
<ul>
    <li class="expanding_mobile_tab mobile_tab_closed"><a class="mobile_smoothscroll">Features <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
    </li>
    <ul class="features_mobile_details_tab">
        <li><span>Registration</span>  <b>FFF FFFF</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Colour</span>  <b>Black</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year</span>  <b>2013</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Fuel Type</span>  <b>Diesel</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Mileage</span>  <b>16336</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Combined MPG</span>  <b>62.80</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Transmission</span>  <b>Automatic</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Tax Band</span>  <b>C</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Engine Size (cc)</span>  <b>1,995</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>CO2 (g/km)</span>  <b>118</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Body Style</span>  <b>2</b> 
        </li>
        <li><span>4 Wheel Drive</span>  <b>No</b> 
        </li>
    </ul>
    <li class='expanding_mobile_tab mobile_tab_closed'><a class='mobile_smoothscroll'>Spec Check <i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i></a>
    </li>
    <ul class='features_mobile_details_tab'>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Armrest front, sliding : £140</li>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Automatic transmission : £1550</li>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Centre armrest for rear seats : £75</li>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Enhanced Bluetooth telephone preparation with USB audio interface and Voice Control : £430</li>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Exterior mirrors - folding, auto dimming : £300</li>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Media package - BMW Business : £990</li>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Metallic paint : £645</li>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Seat heating for driver and front passenger : £325</li>
        <li class='HPI_spec_list_item'>Sun protection glass : £265</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: FYI your `ul`/`li` code is invalid - only `li` elements can be immediate children of `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it as follows:

```
$(".expanding_mobile_tab").on('click', function () {
    $('.expanding_mobile_tab').toggleClass('mobile_tab_closed')
                              .toggleClass('.mobile_tab_open');
    $(".features_mobile_details_tab").not($(this).next()).hide();
    $(this).next('ul').fadeToggle();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".mobile_detail_tabs").offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu8ac6g7/4/)

Answer (score 1):

That is because clicked element does not have the required class used in if condition. You can rather check for visibility of next ul element to make show/hide decision :

```
$(".expanding_mobile_tab").on('click', function () {
 if (! $(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
    $(this).removeClass('mobile_tab_closed').addClass('mobile_tab_open');
    $(".features_mobile_details_tab").hide();
    $(this).next('ul').fadeToggle();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".mobile_detail_tabs").offset().top
    }, 800);
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('mobile_tab_open').addClass('mobile_tab_closed');
    $(this).next('ul').fadeOut();
    console.log('close');
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/07n9r1h1/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu8ac6g7/2/)

```
$(".expanding_mobile_tab").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('mobile_tab_closed')) {
        $(".mobile_tab_open").removeClass('mobile_tab_open').addClass('mobile_tab_closed');
        $(this).removeClass('mobile_tab_closed').addClass('mobile_tab_open');
        $(".features_mobile_details_tab").hide();
        $(this).next('ul').fadeToggle();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".mobile_detail_tabs").offset().top
        }, 800);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('mobile_tab_open').addClass('mobile_tab_closed');
        $(this).next('ul').fadeOut();
        console.log('close');
    }
});
```